# Powershell script to email with attachment from WebRequest Response

Tags: powershell, email, scripting

I have this command which spits out a pdf file and you can see that it is saving in my C: drive:

```
$DownloadReportResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $DownloadReportUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Body $DownloadReportRequestBody -OutFile "C:\Neoload\TestResult-($DateForTestResult).pdf" -TransferEncoding "deflate"
```

Is there way to script this so it can send the file to certain email address as well?

I have this example script to send email, where would I assign the file so it is attached in the email?

```
###########Define Variables######## 

$fromaddress = "myGmail@gmail.com" 
$toaddress = "myGmail@gmail.com"
#$CCaddress = "myGmail@gmail.com" 
$Subject = "ACtion Required" 
$body = get-content .\content.htm 
$attachment = $DownloadReportResponse 
$smtpserver = "smtp.labtest.com" 

#################################### 

$message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$message.From = $fromaddress 
$message.To.Add($toaddress) 
$message.CC.Add($CCaddress) 
$message.Bcc.Add($bccaddress) 
$message.IsBodyHtml = $True 
$message.Subject = $Subject 
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment) 
$message.Attachments.Add($attach) 
$message.body = $body 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver) 
$smtp.Send($message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the build in `Send-MailMessage` command. Just make sure that the attachment is a path to your file

```
$EmailSettings=@{
    SMTPServer="smtp.labtest.com"
    From="myGmail@gmail.com" 
    To="myGmail@gmail.com" 
    Subject="ACtion Required" 
    Body=(get-content .\content.htm )
    Attachments="C:\Neoload\TestResult-($DateForTestResult).pdf"
    BodyAsHtml=$true
}
Send-MailMessage @EmailSettings
```

Comment: Is there way to to assign the attachment right from the $DownloadReportResponse variable? I don't want to assign a path to Attachments.

Comment: Whats in the $DownloadReportResponse variable?

Comment: @Hashim77 You are already defining a path to download the file to, why are you trying to avoid using that same path for the email attachment?

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the saving the file to the disk and rather send it as an attachment over the email.

Comment: $DownloadReportResponse is a response from the Invoke-WebRequest api call. The response of the api is a pdf file.

Comment: @Hashim77 So you basically want the pdf-file NOT to be a file?